# Retrieve data after find user in database table

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await

I use this function to check by `sub` if an user is already present in my database:

```
async function doesUserExist(sub) {
  const response = await InfoDataService.get(sub);
  console.log(response.data);
  if (response.data !== "") {
    /* I wanna GET all user object's properties */
  }
  return false;
}
```

`response.data` is this:
[image]
Firstname, address etc ... are empty because I don't fill out the form every time, to not waste time.

If the user is present, I can see the entire object in the console with all its data: name, surname, email, address etc. 
 I am using ReactJS for the front-end and I would like to be able to show in my app components the user data that I find through this function.
For example in **UsereProfile.js**:

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>{/* retrieved firstame*/}</li>
    <li>{/* retrieved lastname*/}</li>
    <li>{/* retrieved email */}</li>
    <li>{/* retrieved address */}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Since in the asynchronous function If i add `console.log(response.data.firstname)` that shows me the name of the user, I thought it was enough to write:

```
<li>{response.data.firstname}</li>
```

But of course it doesn't work.

**RESOLVED**

```
const initialInfoState = {
      id: null,
      sub: "",
      email: "",
      firstname: "",
      lastname: "",
     
    };

    const [info, setInfo] = useState(initialInfoState);

async function retrieveUserData(sub) {
      try {
        const { data } = await InfoDataService.get(sub);
        return data;
      } catch (error) {
        return null;
      }
    }


    retrieveUserData(sub).then((userData) => {

      setInfo({
        email: userData.email,
        firstname: userData.firstname,
        lastname: userData.lastname,
    
        })
      
    
})
```

Now i can display data in this way, for example:

```
<div> {info.firstname} </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does your response look like? Can you doctor up an example? Second I don't see you using any state management.

```
const [response, setResponse] = useState(); // manages your data and rerenders the component when the data changes

async function doesUserExist(sub) {
    const response = await InfoDataService.get(sub);  

    if(response.data !== "") {
       setResponse(response) // or response.data
    } 
}

useEffect(() => {
   doesUserExist(sub); // call your function once the component loads
}, []); // empty array specifies this should fire once
```

Edit:
Put response.data into your state like so:

```
const [user, setUser] = useState() // might want to set an initial state {}

async function doesUserExist(sub) {
    const response = await InfoDataService.get(sub);

    if (response.data !== "") {
        setUser(response.data)
    }
    return false; // this can probably be removed based on your example
}

// useEffect code from previous example
```

Now in your template you can access it like so:

```
<li>{user?.createdAt}</li>
```

I'm using the "?" here in case you're not setting a default object. JavaScript might complain that property "createdAt" does not exist on type null. The first time the component renders "user" is null or undefined. Once your function runs and pulls the user object into the UI it will re-render and show your values.

Comment: I use state management for the create and update functions and for the input fields. I have not written all the code because it is a lot and I would not want there to be confusion regarding the main problem. If you want I can link my sandbox.

Comment: @KevinNett when I refer to state management I'm talking about using the useState, useEffect etc hooks. You'll have issues like you are when trying to display data if you don't take advantage of those. You'll get used to how to write / use them with practice.

Comment: Yes, but I already use useState for create and update and I don't know how I can reuse it without getting confused.
Look here: https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-gagarin-qtrx7?file=/src/UserInfo.js

Comment: @KevinNett When you call doesUserExist that should be done inside a useEffect. You shouldn't call functions on component load that way or you'll run into problems. Also that function is defined as async but you're using trying to call then() which isn't meant to be used with async. There's no such property 'name' in the example you provided. Change that to 'firstName'. Yet another issue that I see and you can see in the console is that 'sub' is not defined.

Comment: I get `sub` from Auth0 API , i can't get it in codesandbox,but is defined. I really don't understand why i can't use then() , it works!